# Group column data into Week in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have 4 columns which have Date , Account #, Quantity and Sale respectively. I have daily data but I want to be able to show Weekly Sales per Customer and the Quantity.
I have been able to group the column by week, but I also want to group it by OracleNumber, and **Sum** the Quantity and Sales columns. How would I get that to work without messing up the Week format.

```
import pandas as pd
names = ['Date','OracleNumber','Quantity','Sale']
sales = pd.read_csv("CustomerSalesNVG.csv",names=names)
sales['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(sales['Date'])

grouped=sales.groupby(sales['Date'].map(lambda x:x.week))
print(grouped.head())
```

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, you could `groupby` w.r.t the week column and *OracleNumber* column by providing an extra key to the `list` for which the Groupby object has to use and perform `sum` operation later:

```
sales.groupby([sales['Date'].dt.week, 'OracleNumber']).sum()
```